# Get status of current AFS transfers and cache?

Tags: afs

Is there a way to monitor OpenAFS transfers and cache status? I am using the OpenAFS client, and sometimes accessing a certain file (that has not been cached) takes a while. I get impatient because I don't know whether it will be ready soon, or if my connection is down and it will timeout later, or if my program is trying to access a file which it needn't and I can just cancel it, etc.. I would like to be able to see things like:

- Current transfer rate: X kb/s
- Currently downloading files: A, B, C
- Cache X MB / Y MB full
- No connection to host X while trying to download file Y

I am looking for a builtin command that I might have missed, or an API that I can use to write something myself (and put an indicator in my tmux or on my desktop).