# Get information about CVMFS transfers and files in cache

Tags: linux

I am using CVMFS ([CERN Virtual Machine File System](http://cernvm.cern.ch/portal/filesystem)), and it works generally pretty good, but sometimes it takes a while to access a certain file, and I would like to know what is going on. Is it downloading the file I want and soon going to be ready, or is the connection down or slow, or is it caching lots of files that I didn't intend to access, and so on.

Is there a way to get information about current CVMFS transfers, and the status of the cache?

I found `cvmfs_config stat [-v]` which gives me the average transfer rate and amount of cache used, but it can sometimes be very slow and I'm worried about performance (if I run it in a loop to make an indicator for my desktop, for example). Also, I would like more information:

- Current transfers, X kb/s
- Which file is currently being downloaded
- Is there a connnection error, etc.

Is there any API or tool I missed to access this information?

([I also asked a similar question for AFS.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222961/get-status-of-current-afs-transfers-and-cache))